# binary data to image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary representation of a file that i want to write to an image. 
First, I read the file and converted the read data to binary using:

```
def binEncode(st):
    binary = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st)
    return binary
```

Now, how do I write the variable `binary` to a grey scale image?
I tried the following code, but that didn't work:

```
image = open('img.png','wb')
image.write(bytes(convert_to_image))
image.close()
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert data uri to an image? Can you provide a sample of the binary representation?

Comment: That is not how you create binary data; you want to be using bytes or a bytearray, not producing a string of binary numbers.